# SciPy discrete cosine transform (DCT) power in non-existing frequencies

Tags: python, scipy, dct

I try to **transform a simple cosine signal using the Discrete Cosine Transform (DCT) scipy.fft.dct**, however it seems there is an issue as there is **power in frequencies that should not exist**.
Suppose a domain from zero to one, both endpoints included, for the cosine function:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 8, endpoint = True)
f = np.cos(1 * np.pi * x)
```

This simple signal offers a single frequency, so I do expect significant powers only at a single frequency of the DCT:

```
import scipy.fft
f_FT = scipy.fft.dct(f, type = 1, norm = "ortho")
```

I select the **DCT type I** according to the Wikipedia classification (that is also referenced in SciPy's documentation) because the endpoints are included and the signal is even at both boundaries. But this yields as result:

```
array([ 3.35699888e-16,  2.09223516e+00, -1.48359792e-17,  2.21406462e-01,
       -1.92867730e-16,  2.21406462e-01,  1.18687834e-16,  1.56558011e-01])
```

Thus, **there is still significant energy in k=3pi, 5pi, 7pi** (second and last column).

Am I doing something wrong? As written above, **I expect only power at k=1pi**. The Discrete Sine Transform (DST) does not offer this kind of problem - there, I find only power in frequencies that I generate.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Update - origin of problem found**

I found that the problem is caused by norm = "ortho". Apparently, the library modifies the first and last point of the input signal before the transform (in the documentation this is indicated by "If norm='ortho', x[0] and x[N-1] are multiplied by a scaling factor of sqrt(2)") to make sure that Parseval's theorem still holds afterwards. However, then the power in the different modes do not correspond any more to the original signal.

**Solution**

This modification of the original signal is confusing and I propose the following to anybody who also wants Parseval's theorem to hold while still knowing in which modes the original input signal has power:

```
f_DCT = scipy.fft.dct(f, type = 1, norm = "backward")

# Apply manual normalisation similar to: norm = "ortho"
# See documentation of SciPy DCT (y[k]).
scaling_factors = np.zeros(np.shape(f_DCT))
scaling_factors[1:-1] = 0.5 * (np.sqrt(2) / np.sqrt(len(f_DCT) -1))
scaling_factors[0] = 0.5 * (1 / np.sqrt(len(f_DCT) -1))
scaling_factors[-1] = 0.5 * (1 / np.sqrt(len(f_DCT) -1))

f_DCT = f_DCT * scaling_factors
del scaling_factors
# Now f_DCT is scaled as expected for norm = "ortho"

# To check Parseval's theorem, one must scale the weight of the first 
# and last data point because of the specific type I of the DCT. 
# See documentation of SciPy DCT (x[0], x[N-1]).
scaling_factors = np.ones(np.shape(f))
scaling_factors[0] = 1 / np.sqrt(2)
scaling_factors[-1] = 1 / np.sqrt(2)

# Compute the signal weighted properly for checking Parseval's theorem (PT).
f_PT = f * scaling_factors
del scaling_factors

# Note that there is now only energy in one single mode (at k=1pi):
array([ 2.93737402e-16,  1.87082869e+00, -2.31984713e-17,  1.78912008e-16,
       -1.78912008e-16,  2.31984713e-17,  0.00000000e+00, -1.25887458e-16])

# Also, Parseval's theorem holds:
np.sum(f_PT * f_PT)   # 3.499999999999999
np.sum(f_DCT * f_DCT) # 3.499999999999999
```